# How to get net::ERR CONTENT LENGTH MISMATCH in Chrome using express

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, http, express, content-length

For testing purposes I want to see in browser infamous error `net::ERR CONTENT LENGTH MISMATCH`. But the thing is I don't know how. Naïve attempt to just pass wrong `Content-Length` seems not to be working - all the clients just truncate content (btw - is it some well-established, RFC documented behavior?).

Here's a code you can try:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.set({
    'Content-Length': 7,  
  }); 

  // don't use res.send, 
  //it will ignore explicitly set Content-Length in favor of the right one
  res.write('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP');
  res.end();
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('http://127.0.0.1:3000');
});
```

The same holds true for [minimal python server](https://gist.github.com/shabunc/65e76f4428561ee4e4fc0967b5d2be57).
Also I had a crazy thought that may be `express` truncates response whenever content-length is set, but `tcpdump` clearly shows that on client side whole body is received.

Comment: Why do you *want* to see the error?

Comment: @mscdex for testing purposes, exactly for the reasons people sometimes want to see 4xx and 5xx http errors.

Comment: If you want to trigger that error, make the content length value larger than the actual content and call `req.destroy()` after `res.end()`.

Comment: @robertklep awesome, that works indeed, why don't you left an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It looks like most clients don't care if the server sends more data than is stated in `Content-Length`. However, if you send *less* data, and make sure that the connection gets closed server-side (the client won't close it because it thinks there's still more data to come), you can trigger `net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH`:

```
app.get('/ping', function (req, res) {
  res.set({ 'Content-Length': 70 });
  res.write('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP');
  res.end();
  res.connection.end();
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I fixed setting the server.keepAliveTimeout

```
var httpsServer = https.createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('cert.pem'),
    ca: fs.readFileSync('intermediate.crt')
}, app).listen(port);
httpsServer.keepAliveTimeout = 60000 * 2;
httpsServer.listen(port);
```